# How fast are the Taylor series of $\ln(1+x)$ and $\exp(x)$ converging to satisfy the $n$th decimal place? Is it dependend on the input $x$?

Tags: logarithms, real-numbers, exponentiation

How fast are the Taylor series of $\ln(1+x)$ and $\exp(x)$ converging to satisfy the $n$th decimal place? Is it dependend on the input $x$?

$x \in \mathbb R+$.

Maybe you can give an $O(n)$ for that - that means how many terms are needed $O(n)$ to satisfy the $n$th decimal place.

Are there any other good alternatives to calculate the $\ln(1+x)$, than just using tables and Taylor series?

Comment: If you read the full theorem of Taylor's, you will see it includes an error term.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: can you show the relationship between errorterm and O(n)? Does it even make sense to specify an O(n) for those functions with variable inputs ?

Comment: What do you mean by the Taylor series of $\ln x$ ?

Comment: well there is the mercator series (the generic Taylor Series of the natural logarithm of x) and i just want to know how fast/quickly it converges, safisfying the nth decimal place. Maybe it s possible to give it an O(n) for understanding the time complexity for both the Taylorseries of exp(x) and the logarithm.

Comment: Consider the exponential function. Let $\lambda=x/N$ be a number in $(0,1)$. Then $$
\sum\limits_{n = N}^\infty  {\frac{{x^n }}{{n!}}}  = {\rm e}^x \frac{{\gamma (N,x)}}{{\Gamma (N)}} \sim \frac{1}{{1 - \lambda }}\frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi N} }}({\rm e}\lambda )^N 
$$ for large $N$, by [$(8.4.7)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4.E7), [$(8.11.6)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11.E6) and Stirling's formula. You can use this to find $N$ for a given $x$ that makes the error smaller than $10^{-n}$.

Comment: The Mercator series is for $\ln(1+x)$ and not for $\ln(x)$.

Comment: For $\ln(1+x)$ you can try something I did for $\arctan(x)$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4216465).

Comment: this is interesting.